# how to Show and Hide checked value ontime without refresh or clicking any thing using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to achive ontime checked value text and disable the text if unchecked. i tried this what is missing in my code.

Here is My form code:

```
<div class="products-row">
    <?php $lq=$conn->query("select * from os_lunch where lunch_status=1 order by id_lunch ASC");
        while ($lunch = $lq->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"> 
            <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $lunch['id_lunch'];?>" hidden>
                <label for="<?php echo $lunch['id_lunch'];?>"><img src="img/lunch/<?php echo $lunch['lunch_image']; ?>" alt="" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
                <h3 id="lunchname" ><?php echo $lunch['lunch_name'];?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

And this my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var FoodMenu = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
            return $(this).next('#lunchname').text();
        }).get().join("<br>");
        $("#selectedfood").html(FoodMenu);
    });
</script>
```

I want to Show the output here:

```
<div class="related-row" id="FoodSelected">
    <h4 class="text-center">Food Selected</h4> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a id="selectedfood"></a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

[Click Here To see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4opTf.png)

Comment: Aside .... ID's must be unique so the `h3`element can't be always `lunchname``

Comment: what is ON_TIME???

Comment: @taseenb it means, when i clicked checked any thing, the text of that checkbox appear on same page, without any click or refresh is it possible..?

Comment: Instead of giving id=lunchname, define a css class called 'lunchname'.  change to - <h3 class="lunchname" ><?php echo $lunch['lunch_name'];?></h3> . Then change your script function line to - return $(this).next('.lunchname').text();  Give it a go. Should work.